# Jenkins - Getting console output with timestamps behind global authentication

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My company uses *global authentication* method to access different services including Jenkins (once logged in - you don't need to provide credentials anymore to whatever company services until logout).

Because of that I can't use *curl* or *wget* to get **$JENKINS_URL/../console**
In my case I need to do a complex parsing by time of a plain text with timestamps (Timestamper plugin):
**$JENKINS_URL/../timestamps/?time=HH:mm:ss**
but can't figure out how to parse or save timestamp output from the actual job.
The closest option I found is to use groovy: **def log = manager.build.logFile.text** , but it is a plain text without timestamps.

Maybe some plugin can help me with this?

P.S.: I don't have access to actual Jenkins server

Comment: Did you look here? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Answer (score 0):

You can use your API token with any user registered in the system to authenticate your request. see here for examples: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

For example:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=user --http-password=apiToken --secure-protocol=TLSv1 http://jenkins.yourcompany.com/job/your_job/build?token=TOKEN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it using API token but didn't succeeded. What I found is a small plugin that I think might be useful: [jenkins-log-console-log](https://github.com/cboylan/jenkins-log-console-log) .